# Swift, how can I get a property

Tags: swift, string

I tried to have a string property show different languages by if condition. The last statement shows error! How can I get the member value?

```
struct EN {
    let hello = "Hello!"
}

struct CN {
    let hello = "Hi!"
}

var stringObj:Any?

var language = "CN"

if language == "EN" {
    stringObj = EN()
}

if language == "CN" {
    stringObj = CN()
}

print(stringObj!)   // "CN(hello: "Hi!")\n"  on playground

print(stringObj!.hello) // error! has no member "hello"
```

Comment: Your stringObj is type of Any?... Any? doesn't have the hello property... You will have to cast your Object... Or use a protocol as a superclass that supports your hello

Comment: @LeoDabus He really should define a common protocol here. Please see Palle answer...

Comment: I think he should use NSLocalizedString. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

As you have declared `stringObj` with the type `Any?`, the Swift compiler has no idea what its actual type is or what properties it has.

If both types `CN` and `EN` have a common property, you can use a protocol to specify this:

```
protocol Language {
     var hello: String { get }
}

struct EN: Language {...}
struct CN: Language {...}

var stringObj: Language?

...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems solve my problem. I want user to be able to change UI languages on-the-fly, so didn't consider to use NSLocalizedString.